# change background color of view by its ID in Titanium

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have several views that are added to a ScrollView dynamically with a for, but when the user clicks on one of the views, I want to change the Background color of the view. I have the following code for the click event:

```
(function() {
    var id = i;
    viewQuantity.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        viewQuantity.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    });
})();
```

but with this code the view that changes the color is always the last added view. How can I use the id to change the view that was clicked by the user?

Comment: You should add "Titanium" to your question. I found your question using the iOS tag, and could help you in a native iOS app, but know almost nothing about Titanium. (sorry)

Comment: Well, @Manuel_Rodrigues! Please put up more key code or tell us in details of your problem.

Comment: the variable 'id' is the id of the view. so wen i click on it and show an alert with the clicked view id it shows 1 ore 2 ore 3 depending on which was pressed. But now I want to change the background color of the view that was click by the user. the only Id code that i have is the code that i posted. if there is a better way to set an id to a view an then change the background color of it on an click event i appreciate if you cold tel mi how to implement it. i'm not using the alloy folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a click event you get an event property in the function as first parameter. This has `source` object which is the element the user has clicked.

```
var clickedView;
(function() {
    var id = i;
    viewQuantity.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (clickedView){
             clickedView.backgroundColor= '#000000'; // put your own color here to restore original
        }
        e.source.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
        clickedView = e.source;
    });
})();
```

To change the color later, you can store a reference to the object, and change the color later

Comment: thank's it has worked for my problem but now wen i try the same code to change a label color with the following line (e.source.labelX.color = 'black') it gives me an error saying that undefined is not an object

Comment: I added restoring original color to the answer. If it helped you, please upvote and mark the answer as solution ;)

Comment: I changed the e.source.backroundColor to viewQuantity.backgroundColor and the clickedView = e.souce to clickedView = viewQuantity because i have a label inside the view and when i clicked on the label the background color that was changes was the color of the label and not the view because the e. source returns the object of the label when i click it and not of the view. but thanks your suggestion help'd me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView();

var lastClickedView;

for(var i = 0;i<=10;i++){
    (function(){
        var view = Ti.UI.createView();
        var label = Ti.UI.createLabel();
        view.add(label);
        scrollView.add(view);
        view.addEventListener('click',function(){
            if(lastClickedView){
                lastClickedView.backgroundColor = '#000';
                lastClickedView.children[0].color = '#000';
            }
            view.backgroundColor = '#fff';
            label.color = '#fff';
            lastClickedView = view;
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: the second part o your post has worked to change the color of the table but I become a new error that happens when I click on top of the table and not on the view. why does the event activate on the click in the label and the view?

Comment: My bad. `e.source` could be the label, so `e.source.children` could throw an error. Just use the first solution. It should work fine. It is expected for the `click` to be fired when you click on the label, since it's added to the view and the event bubbles up.

Comment: it has worked completely but now imagine that i have two views and when i click on the first view it changes the background color. when i click the second view it changes the background color too but i need to reset the background color of the first view when i click on the second view. how can i do that?

Comment: Just maintain a reference to the last clicked view. See my updated answer.